# Crop the bottom of a UIImage after resizing

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

I have this image (original size)

[image: Image to resize]

And I want to resize the image preserving the aspect ratio to 600 x 600. After that, I would like to crop just the bottom to this frame: `{0, 400, 600, 200}` in order to get the bottom part of the image.

Resizing with preserving the aspect ratio works well, but I'm unable to crop the bottom of the image. I'm using this code to resize with aspect ratio:

```
CGFloat horizontalRatio = bounds.width / self.size.width;
CGFloat verticalRatio = bounds.height / self.size.height;
CGFloat ratio;

switch (contentMode) {
    case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
        ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
        break;

    case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
        ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d", contentMode];
}

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * ratio, self.size.height * ratio);
UIImage *resizedImg = [self resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:quality];
if (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill == contentMode && (newSize.height > bounds.height || newSize.width > bounds.width)) {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake((newSize.width - bounds.width) / 2, (newSize.height - bounds.height) / 2, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], bounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return croppedImage;
}
return resizedImg;
```

And this code to crop the bottom

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 400, 600, 200);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([newImage CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

And this is the result I'm getting (I should get the same image, I want to make that crop to blur the bottom crop area to display some text):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/Adrian2112/UIImage-BlurredFrame) helped me to solve the issue. I was initializing the frame of the image with wrong values.

Comment: Can you specifically show what part of the frame that had the wrong values in code? Thanks.

Comment: The bottom frame had the same size of the image but with different ``y`` position. If you want to achieve the same results, check this ``UIImage`` category: https://github.com/Adrian2112/UIImage-BlurredFrame

Answer (score 0):

its very simple

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)oldImage {

CGSize imageSize = oldImage.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSizeMake( imageSize.width,
                                                    imageSize.height - 200),
                                        NO,
                                        0.);
[oldImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake( 0, -100)
            blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy
                alpha:1.];

UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return croppedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping

This is what saved me!!

```
func cropImage(_ inputImage: UIImage, toRect cropRect: CGRect, viewWidth: CGFloat, viewHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage? 
{    
let imageViewScale = max(inputImage.size.width / viewWidth,
                         inputImage.size.height / viewHeight)

// Scale cropRect to handle images larger than shown-on-screen size
let cropZone = CGRect(x:cropRect.origin.x * imageViewScale,
                      y:cropRect.origin.y * imageViewScale,
                      width:cropRect.size.width * imageViewScale,
                      height:cropRect.size.height * imageViewScale)

// Perform cropping in Core Graphics
guard let cutImageRef: CGImage = inputImage.cgImage?.cropping(to:cropZone)
else {
    return nil
}

// Return image to UIImage
let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
return croppedImage
}
```

Comment: Hi @devjme
I used the same function, but it's giving me a landscape image instead of portrait.
Function call : 

    `UIImage* croppedImage = [self cropImage:image toRect:CGRectMake(self.capturedImageView.frame.size.width / 4, 0, self.capturedImageView.frame.size.width/2, self.capturedImageView.frame.size.height) viewWidth:self.capturedImageView.frame.size.width viewHeight:self.capturedImageView.frame.size.height];`

Any help would be appreciated .